# database normalization users and messages database

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a newbie with databases and I want to create a database which will have

1. Username VARCHAR(16)
2. Membership status ( paid or free )
3. Message  TEXT (most likely or should I use something else?)
4. Messages counter for a user 'to count the total number of messages for a user (probably UNSIGNED INT).
5. Catagory of the message VARCHAR(60)
6. Date posted DATE

Now I have this as a layout for the database I am not sure how to get it to the first and second and third normal forms.
Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The 1NF shouldn't be too difficult, surely you can think of something?

Comment: I might suggest 2NF should be category, memberbership status be on a different table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you want a user table:

```
UserID, UserName, member_status
```

And a message table:

```
UserID, category, date, message
```

A category table:

```
category, description
```

You can get the total number of messages for a user with a query like:

```
select count(*) from message where userid = 'someuser'
```

so don't store that.

Hope this gets you started. Have fun...

Comment: Should I use the UserID as my primary key?

Comment: Yes, or if names are always unique you could just use that.